# Cannot do save_screenshot give NotSupportedByDriver in Capybara/Poltergeist

Tags: capybara, poltergeist

I am running Capybara with Poltergeist and I have a step:

```
Given(/^take a screenshot$/) do
  page.save_screenshot("/tmp/page.png", :full => true)
end
```

And it keeps saying:

```
Capybara::Driver::Base#save_screenshot (Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError)
./features/step_definitions/job_steps.rb:19:in `/^take a screenshot$/'
features/jobs_board/user_management.feature:9:in `And take a screenshot'
```

Any ideas where to look? My config in env.rb looks like this:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to add:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
```

And change

```
require 'poltergeist'
```

to

```
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
```

Comment: i had problems in mac os x and had to use  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist, then some version update (not sure which), meant i had to duse Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist